# Employee Skill Workbook - Button/Macro for adding new employees

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use excel as a tool for phone representatives to filter technicians based on their particular skill type, as well as allow a button on the spreadsheet that allows for a new user to be input.

We have a working spreadsheet that allows the user to select either a skill or technician name and it filters for you, however we cannot seem to be able to add a button that allows for new data to be put across multiple sheets in rows that are unfilled.

I have looked through a few macros, but none are around that let the user simply type the name of the new employee and have it added, without having to mess with the other sheets...Pictures are below

```
[UserFrontEnd][1]
[Slicer Data][2]
[CheckBoxData][3]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTXY0.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvDKk.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrXTJ.png
```

Comment: This is a bit vague to be helpfully answered. Providing details on the sheets that exist, how they currently relate to one another, and how they would need to be updated might allow someone to help you better.

Comment: I added images of the workbook pages.